# Does tez get credited to your account if you free storage (delete bytes)?

Tags: storage

Storing data in the Tezos blockchain costs tez, which is burned. Does the reverse direction work in reverse?

In other words, if I free storage (delete bytes), will I get freshly-minted tez?

IIUC, Ethereum does credit ETH when storage is freed, and various Ethereans have used this mechanism to hedge against future increases in gas / storage costs. It seems like a rather clever hedging mechanism that would be fun to play with on Tezos, if it exists.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure nothing like that exists in Tezos. In 3+ years, never heard/read anything like that. Plus, this is an immutable blockchain. How do you delete data? Once it's written, you can't erase what has been baked by a block.

Comment: IIUC, the history is immutable, but the head state isn't. E.g. when I transfer an FA1.2 token it mutates the storage in the corresponding contract, e.g. to say I have more or less of the given token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you pay for storage and then later remove the value, you are not refunded the storage fee.

This has been discussed in the developer slack, and I believe has been recorded as a feature request somewhere